# Solving an equation and ODE simultaneously

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a differential equation like $y'+a*y+b=0$.
I have to find the value of $u=c*y+d$.
These are the simplified form of the ODE and equation.
Also, I have to plot $y$ and $u$ together.

Comment: Please include the Mathematica code you already have tried, so that readers can help you improve it..

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct site? Do you need a ***Mathematica*** code, or do you need to solve analytically those equations? In the latter case you should probably go on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: (1) You can do this easily by hand. [Wikipedia has an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients) with $a=3$, $b=-2$. (2) The plot depends on the parameters, or at least the general shape & orientation depend on $a$ and $c$.  To plot the functions in *Mathematica* you would need to assign all four numeric values. What are they? Or are you asking a general mathematics question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+ay\left(  x\right)  =-b
$$

For the homogeneous part $\frac{dy}{dx}+ay=0$, $\frac{dy}{y}=-adx$, integrating
once gives
\begin{align*}
\ln y  & =-ax+C\\
y_{h}  & =C_{1}e^{-ax}
\end{align*}

For the particular solution, try $y_{p}=k$. Substitute into the ODE\ gives
$ak=-b$ or $k=-\frac{b}{a}$. Hence $y_{p}=\frac{-b}{a}$, therefore the full
solution is

\begin{align*}
y  & =y_{h}+y_{p}\\
& =C_{1}e^{-ax}-\frac{b}{a}
\end{align*}

Where $C_{1}$ is constant of integration. Therefore

\begin{align*}
u  & =cy+d\\
& =c\left(  C_{1}e^{-ax}-\frac{b}{a}\right)  +d
\end{align*}

To plot, need first to determine $C_{1}$ which requires initial conditions.
Also need numerical values for $c$ and $b$ and $a$ and $d$. Then use the `Plot`
command in Mathematica.

If you have to use Mathematica to solve the ODE, the command is

`DSolve[y'[x] + a*y[x] == -b, y[x], x]`

For example, using some numbers:

```
b = 1; a = 2;
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{y'[x] + a*y[x] == -b, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x];
c = 10; d = 11;
u = c*sol + d;
Plot[u, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is ok, but i have to plot u and y together in a graph i have to measure change of u with respect to y. Thank u.